# The text on my buttons is stuck to the bottom right of their padding

Tags: html, css

While attempting to develop a clean sidebar for use on my website, I noticed that the text in my buttons was getting stuck to the bottom right of their padding. I also observed that when I removed the styling on their borders, the problem went away.

I've tried several potential solutions and found the same outcome.

```css
body {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }

            * {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            input[type=button] {
                position: relative;
                top: 20px;
                left: 25px;

                margin-bottom: 20px;

                border-radius: 12.5px;
                border: none;

                padding-top: 15px;
                padding-left: 100px;

                transition-duration: 0.7s;
            }

                input[type=button]:hover {
                    background-color: #00aaff;
                    border-color: white;
                    color: white;
                }

            #sideBar {
                background: linear-gradient(#5900ff, #8000ff, #ae00ff);
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 220px;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sideBar">
            <input type="button" value="Test Button"  />
            <input type="button" value="Test Button"  />
            <input type="button" value="Test Button"  />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text inside the button element is centered by default. However if you apply padding only on one side, the text will appear pushed to the opposite side. Remove the padding, or add padding-right as well, to omit this effect.